# Interface Builder - where is the documentation

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have many times looked for XCode documentation for things like (1.) icons in the editor intellisense. My latest documentation problem is in Interface Builder:

When you have a .xib file. Then you have "Placeholders" for "File's Owner" and the UIView itself - (2.) Where should I set "custom class" & (3.) what is "Inherited From Target"

Can you help me help finding informations for XCode UI/IB documentations?

Answer (score 40):

I can help on the "Inherited from Target" option of Custom Class.

My project has a variety of targets (free, paid, home free, home paid) and I have a class that is only used in the home variants.

When I just added my class and let it default to Module I kept getting an error at run time that the class was not defined in the storyboard.

By checking the "Inherited from Target" option the module gets compiled in for the targets I use it in (Target Memberships for swift file and everything works.

I am assuming this was an optimization so the module would not be included when not needed - but that is just a guess.

Needless to say this wasted an entire day to figure out - hope it helps some others.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to lack of proper documentation, developing for Apple is like this: 10 seconds to add a feature, 10 hours to make it work.

Comment: Saved my time! To be more specific, in my case, I defined a custom view A and, if I add it programmatically to another view, then it's fine for A to be **NOT** inherited. But if you add it to another view in storyboard without this option checked, it will prompt the famous `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key` error which looks like you did something wrong when connecting the IBOutlet...

Comment: In my case, the "Inherited from Target" button is disabled. What should I do?